# Trigger After Update for a Specific Value

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Is it possible to create a trigger on SQL Server that will execute when a column value is updated to a specific value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[Employee_Test] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    declare @empid int;
    declare @empname varchar(100);
    declare @empsal decimal(10,2);
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

select @empid=i.Emp_ID from inserted i; 
select @empname=i.Emp_Name from inserted i; 
select @empsal=i.Emp_Sal from inserted i;   

if update(Emp_Name)
    set @audit_action='Updated Record -- After Update Trigger.';
if update(Emp_Sal)
    set @audit_action='Updated Record -- After Update Trigger.';

insert into Employee_Test_Audit(Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
values(@empid,@empname,@empsal,@audit_action,getdate());

PRINT 'AFTER UPDATE Trigger fired.'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple trigger and hoping that it helps you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [FUND].[TRU_FUND_FUND_PRICE] ON [FUND].[FUND_PRICE] 
  AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @PRICE_ID BIGINT
DECLARE @UNIT_PRICE DECIMAL(18,7)
DECLARE @UNIT_PRICE_BEFORE_UPDATE DECIMAL(18,7)
DECLARE @TOTAL_SHARE_BEFORE_UPDATE DECIMAL(18,7)
DECLARE @TOTAL_SHARE DECIMAL(18,7)
DECLARE @RECORD_STATUS_BEFORE_UPDATE CHAR(1)
DECLARE @RECORD_STATUS CHAR(1)

SELECT  @UNIT_PRICE_BEFORE_UPDATE=UNIT_PRICE ,  @TOTAL_SHARE_BEFORE_UPDATE = TOTAL_SHARE, @RECORD_STATUS_BEFORE_UPDATE =RECORD_STATUS  FROM DELETED

SELECT @PRICE_ID = PRICE_ID,@UNIT_PRICE=UNIT_PRICE,@TOTAL_SHARE=TOTAL_SHARE,@RECORD_STATUS=RECORD_STATUS FROM INSERTED  

--You can compare to specific values instead of deleted data

IF @UNIT_PRICE=@UNIT_PRICE_BEFORE_UPDATE AND @TOTAL_SHARE =@TOTAL_SHARE_BEFORE_UPDATE  AND @RECORD_STATUS_BEFORE_UPDATE = @RECORD_STATUS
BEGIN
    RETURN
END

INSERT INTO FUND.FUND_PRICE_LOG (
    [PRICE_ID],
    [FUND_ID],
    [PRICE_DATE],
    [UNIT_PRICE],
    [UPDATE_USER_CODE],
    [UPDATE_PROG_CODE],
    [UPDATE_DATE],
    [OPERATION],
    [RECORD_STATUS],
    [TOTAL_SHARE],
    [LIMIT_CHANGE_AMOUNT]
)
SELECT [PRICE_ID], [FUND_ID], [PRICE_DATE],
[UNIT_PRICE],
[UPDATE_USER_CODE],
[UPDATE_PROG_CODE],
GETDATE(),
'U',
[RECORD_STATUS],
[TOTAL_SHARE] ,
([TOTAL_SHARE] - @TOTAL_SHARE_BEFORE_UPDATE)
FROM INSERTED

END

GO
```